# DDL Hive SQL for raw data wrapped in []

Tags: sql, hive, ddl

DDL Hive SQL for raw data wrapped in []

Hello,

So i have a .txt data consist of 1000 rows data with below format:
[a, "b", c, d, "e", f, "123, 4567, 89101, 2345"]

I want to create hive table based on them and tried below DDL query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
col1 int,
col2 string,
col3 bigint,
col4 int,
col5 string,
col6 int
col7 array<string>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\001'
```

and when I loaded the txt file into the created table, it seems that the data presented is not what I want, where the contents of the table should be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f | 123, 4567, 89101, 2345 |

while what happened was:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [a | "b" | c | d | "e" | f | [123]] |

here's the issues:
-value of col1 is included with the '[', same with col7 with ']'
-some columns with value consist of "" still included,
-value of col7 is truncated, i think bc the system recognize the , in "" value as delimiter.

I still don't know how to solve it. any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this import a 1 time activity or do you expect the exact same file format for import regularly? Can you use python or similar to pre-process the file before import?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell, for now, it's simple import from hdfs to hive. But the plan is will be flow regularly with one file consist of mio rows

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the leading and trailing characters `[` and `]` in the input file before loading the data into the table, use a script or a tool like sed or awk.

To import a file with each row containing a mix of quoted and unquoted fields into a Hive table use the ROW FORMAT SERDE clause to specify a custom Serializer-Deserializer (SerDe) that can handle the quoted fields with commas. The OpenCSVSerde provided by Hive enables this: e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  col1 int,
  col2 string,
  col3 bigint,
  col4 int,
  col5 string,
  col6 int,
  col7 array<string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
LOCATION '/path/to/myfile';
```

see: [OpenCSVSerDe for processing CSV](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html)

To remove the leading [ and trailing ] characters from each line of a file using Python, you can read the file line by line and use the strip() method  e.g:

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as infile, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('[]\n')
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

**untested!**